# Typescript coding styling with then method accepting a declared function

Tags: javascript, typescript, syntax, callback, es6-promise

I am struggling with typeScript syntax used in the snippet below. Can someone kindly clear it out for me.

```
type Reply = (reply: Replies.AssertExchange) => string

const announce: (text: string) => Reply = (text: string): Reply => {
  return (reply: Replies.AssertExchange): string => {
    return `${text} ${(reply as Replies.AssertExchange).exchange}`
  }
}

channel.assertExchange('someName', 'fanout').then(announce('Exchange assertion'))
```

Here the return type of method `channel.assertExchange()`
is promise i.e `Promise<Replies.AssertExchange>`

The style that is confusing me is, normally the `.then()` function should take the returned object i.e `Replies.AssertExchange` or a function working on the return object without arguments. However, here it's taking a function with string argument i.e `announce('Exchange assertion')`.

would be nice if an example is presented in a normal `.then()` form.

Comment: `.then((reply) => { return announce('Exchange assertion')(reply) });`

Comment: Thanks @ritaj can you present it without using the ```reply()```function i.e using an arrow function.

Comment: Please share reproducable example

Comment: @captain-yossarian it is simply a syntax confusion for me. I think there is no need to share reproducable examples. However,  if u want then here u can find many examples https://www.codota.com/code/javascript/functions/amqplib/Channel/assertExchange

Comment: `.then(function (reply) { return announce('Exchange assertion')(reply) });`

Comment: there is no "normal" form of `then` method, only its signature accepting a function as its argument (making `then` a higher order function). You need to read up on partial application - `announce` is simply a curried function. This has nothing to do with TypeScript syntax.

Comment: here is what it looks like with types stripped out, I hope this makes it clear how `then` accepts a result of calling the function: `const announce = (text) => (reply) => \`${text} ${reply.exchange}\`;`

Comment: the function is also excessively typed and its implementation is unnecessary bloated, here is how the type could be defined: `type announce = (text: string) => (reply: Replies.AssertExchange) => string;`. And the whole function would be: `const announce: announce = (text) => (reply) => \`${text} ${(reply).exchange}\`;`

Comment: @OlegValter you are right, it was such a confusing bloated function. Kindly add your comment as an answer so that i accept it as a resolve. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, it is very neat-looking after the bloat is cleared away. There were several problems: unnecessary type assertion, mixing of inline and aliased types, explicit annotations where TS can infer types and mix of shortcut body with block-style body :) No need for answer here - if I have time, will add a dupe target about partial application, since the question boils down to it

Comment: Also, upon rereading my comments, I find hem somewhat rude-sounding in their abruptness - which was not my intention. Too much information to cram into comment character limit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The style that is confusing me is, normally the `.then()` function should take the returned object i.e `Replies.AssertExchange` or a function working on the return object without arguments. However, here it's taking a function with string argument i.e `announce('Exchange assertion')`.

`announce` is a double arrow function.  It is a function which returns a function (also known as "currying").

These two statements are the same:

```
.then(announce('Exchange assertion'))
```

```
.then(reply => announce('Exchange assertion')(reply))
```

Using a curried function means that you can avoid having to write out the `reply =>` part.  The value of `announce('Exchange assertion')` is exactly what you think it should be -- a function that takes a `Replies.AssertExchange` as its argument.

I agree that the `announce` function is written in a very confusion way.  This line in particular is convoluted:

```
const announce: (text: string) => Reply = (text: string): Reply => {
```

The first `: (text: string) => Reply` gives the type of the variable `announce`.  It is a function that takes a `string` and returns a `Reply`.

The second `= (text: string): Reply =>` is the implementation.

This sort of duplicated typing is not necessary.  We can just provide types for the implementation and typescript will be able to figure out the type for the variable `announce` based on that.

Perhaps this makes it a bit clearer:

```
const announce = (text: string) => 
  (reply: Replies.AssertExchange): string => 
    `${text} ${reply.exchange}`;
```

When you call `announce` with a `text: string`, you get a function `(reply: Replies.AssertExchange): string`.

So the type of `announce('Exchange assertion')` is `(reply: Replies.AssertExchange): string`.

Comment: I also think a type assertion is unnecessary  (since the `reply` is annotated as such: `Replies.AssertExchange` - or am I missing something?) as well as the explicit `string` annotation in the return position - afaik it is inferred from using a template literal.

Comment: @Oleg I totally overlooked the `as`!  I will edit that as yes, it it terrible.  As far as the return `:string` it can be inferred but I usually put return types on my functions for readability.  It's just a matter of preference but it's not strictly required.

Comment: It is quite elusive - when I was typing in my comment for the first time, I also did not notice it :) Re: annotation - yeah, just wasn't sure whether you missed it or left in intentionally (given the `as` assertion). I personally don't like explicitly typing inferred types inline, but it is certainly useful when separating typings from the implementation and agree about preferenciality (although the handbook does encourage inferring more as far as I recall).

Comment: @Oleg For me I usually write the return type first so I like knowing what the return type is "supposed" to be so that I can get errors if my implementation doesn't match my expectation.

Comment: Don't argue with that (off-note: sorry, voting misclick) - I do that too from time to time, only cleaning up afterwards (and if it is worth the effort)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Unfortunately the coding rules are strictly typed where i work. Therefore, it was quite confusing to get grasp of the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for readability, perhaps async/await is better than `.then()`?

```
// Let TypeScript infer the return types and cache
// the announceExchangeAssertion function...

const announceExchangeAssertion = (
  { exchange }: Replies.AssertExchange
) => `Exchange assertion: ${exchange}`;

// Example using async/await...

foo();
async function foo() {
  const reply = await channel.assertExchange('name', 'fanout');
  announceExchangeAssertion(reply);

  // which is exactly the same as...

  announceExchangeAssertion(
    await channel.assertExchange('name', 'fanout')
  );
}

// Example using promise chaining...

channel
  .assertExchange('name', 'fanout')
  .then((reply) => announceExchangeAssertion(reply));

// Which is exactly the same as...

channel
  .assertExchange('name', 'fanout')
  .then(announceExchangeAssertion);
```